# GitHub .md files to WordPress pages

Tags: github, markdown

I saw some websites that manage their information/documentation in a GitHub repository. This allows everyone to create issues if something is wrong or outdated, propose changes by forking/request push etc.

Is it possible to link WordPress to a GitHub repository?

Expected behavior: every .md-file in the repository becomes a page (or post) in WordPress (ideally keeping the markdown layout). When a change is made in the GitHub repository, the changes should immediately reflect in WordPress.

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is yes, I'm not sure what depth of information would otherwise be the correct answer to your question, as it's currently quite broad. To get you started, if you search for Github repo API, you'll find lots of info, and I'm sure there are questions here involving the creation of content from an API.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a plugin called [WordPress GitHub Sync](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-github-sync/). It should be able to synchronize both ways.

It hasn't been updated in 5 months and it lacks a lot of documentation but I was able to import a file from my GitHub repository into WordPress.

I still have to figure out how it exactly works, but it's what I have been looking for.